# Deleting empty elements from vector

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c++11, vector

I am trying to delete empty entries from `std::vector`. Here is a sample code, but something is wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> s1 = {"a"," ", "", "b","c","   ","d"};
    for (auto it = s1.begin(); it != s1.end() && isspace(*it); )
{
        it = s1.erase(it);
}

    std::cout<<"vector size = "<<s1.size();
    for (auto &i:s1) 
        std::cout<<i<<"\n";      

}
```

I am running a `for` loop to find out empty elements and deleting from there. There should be STL method too, but not sure how it will work.

Comment: [`isspace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) expects an `int` (historically, but actually a character) but you provide a `std::string`. That's not compatible. You could check instead `(*it == "" || *it == " ")`.

Comment: Your `for` loop tries to delete "empty" entries only from the beginning of the `vector`. As soon as it encounters a single non-"empty" entry - it stops.

Comment: When you think "something is wrong", you should think about *why* you think something is wrong. Does it compile or not? Is there a compilation error? If not, does it behave as you expected? How do you expect it to behave? How does it behave?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: `std::remove_if` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "a", " ", "", "b", "c", "   ", "d" };

    auto is_empty = []( const std::string &s )
    {
        return s.find_first_not_of( " \t" ) == std::string::npos;
    };

    v.erase( std::remove_if( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), is_empty ), std::end( v ) );

    for ( const auto &s : v )
    {
        std::cout << "\"" << s << "\" ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"a" "b" "c" "d"
```

As for your code then it is inefficient because you are trying to remove each found element separately and this loop for example

```
for (auto it = s1.begin(); it != s1.end() && isspace(*it); )
{
    it = s1.erase(it);
}
```

can iterate never because the first element is not satisfies the condition `isspace(*it)` that moreover is invalid. That is you are supplying an object of the type `std::string` to a function that expects an object of the type `char` (more precisely of the type `int`).

If to use the C function `isspace` then the program can look the following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "a", " ", "", "b", "c", "   ", "d" };

    auto is_empty = []( const std::string &s )
    {
        return std::all_of( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ), 
                            []( char c ) 
                            { 
                                return std::isspace( ( unsigned char )c );
                            } );
    };

    v.erase( std::remove_if( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), is_empty ), std::end( v ) );

    for ( const auto &s : v )
    {
        std::cout << "\"" << s << "\" ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.